# How to account for ng-if when verifying if an element is present?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have a div on my page that is hidden by ng-if sometimes. I want to devise a test that checks whether the element is present ONLY when it should be present. ng-if completely removes the element from the DOM if the test fails.

I tried to write an if statement in protractor that evaluated the same thing that my ng-if is evaluating and then expect a value only if that evaluated to true but it looks like protractor isn't aware of non-dom elements, which makes sense but leaves me a little stumped as to what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is [`.isPresent()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent) method that checks for presence of an element in the DOM:

```
expect(elm.isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

You can also use [`.evaluate()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) to evaluate the `ng-if` value:

```
expect(elm.evaluate("ng_if_value")).toBe(false);
```

Comment: I'm not able to evaluate ng-if because the element is completely removed from the DOM. Upon inspection the only thing that is left when evaluating to false is a comment :

<!-- ngIf: docsEndpoint.Endpoint.Parameters.length -->

How would I go about evaluating that?

Comment: @Crhistian sure, locate the controller or a parent element and evaluate in it's context instead.

Comment: Grabbing a parent element doesn't pull in the commented out element for me to evaluate and the controller is defined in ui-router so its also not part of the DOM. Just for learning sake though to evaluate in the context of a controller I would basically just check that specific property of the controller right? Something like Controller.property.propertytoCheck?

Here is the page I'm looking at if you're curious https://devcenter.ordercloud.io/docs/BuyerPerspective/Me/Get. The part that needs to be evaluated is docsEndpoint.Endpoint.RequestBody.Sample

Really appreciate all your help

Answer (score 0):

For this solution, we need to check first, element is present or not

```
<div id="status" ng-if="data.isDeleted">  
     <span id="delete_status"> Deleted </span> 
</div>
```

> If data.isDeleted is true than we do expect further

```
var statusId= element(by.id('status'));
statusId.isPresent().then(function (present){
   if(present){
      expect(statusId.evaluate("data.isDeleted")).toBeTruthy();
      expect(statusId.element(by.id("delete_status")).getText()).toContain("Deleted");
   }
});
```